# Changing the default name for connection strings AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsDashboard for WebJobs

Tags: c#, azure, connection-string, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am adding a webjob project to a website project. Webjob project requires AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsDashboard connection strings in the environment when deployed to Azure. Is it possible to change the name of these connection strings, i.e. MyAzureWebJobsDashboard and MyAzureWebJobsDashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection string names themselves are not configurable. They *are* settable via the `JobHostConfiguration.StorageConnectionString` and `JobHostConfiguration.DashboardConnectionString` properties, which would allow you to read and set them however you choose.

However, that *won't* work for the WebJobs Dashboard itself - it reads the settings directly from the app settings set in the portal and expects these well known names.